# Manually running a .ps1 in an administrator (elevated) shell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, administrator

I have a seemingly straightforward question: How can I manually run a .ps1 script on Server 2012 R2 and have it open in an administrator elevated shell?  I am right clicking and clicking "Run with Powershell" on the .ps1 file.

My environment:

Two Server 2012 R2 machines in the same domain in the same OU.  Both are full GUI installs. Both have UAC set to "default".

The discrepancy:

One of the servers will run any and all .ps1 files in an administrator elevated shell.  The other server will run any and all .ps1 files in a non-administrator, standard shell.  I have no idea what the differences are between the two servers.  Neither are running any custom Powershell profiles.

The following registry keys are all identical between the two servers:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellCmdletDefinitionXML.1

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellConsole.1

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellData.1

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellSessionConfiguration.1

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellXMLData.1

What am I missing?

Comment: I found two methods with which to solve this issue:

1. Disable UAC... I know, I know... obvious, right?  Nope! Server 2012 R2 is different than 2008 regarding how to FULLY disable UAC: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13953.windows-server-2012-deactivating-uac.aspx

2. In Local Security Policy, Local Policies, Security Options, set the option of "User Account Control: Use Admin Approval Mode for the built-in Administrator account" to "disabled" and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

A quick foray with Google ended me up with a [posting on Ben Armstrong's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script.aspx) where he posted code that auto-elevated a script if it was needed. Here's the code he posted that seems perfect for your needs:

```
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
 $myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
 $myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

 # Get the security principal for the Administrator role
 $adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

 # Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
 if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
    {
    # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
    clear-host
    }
 else
    {
    # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator

    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
    $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;

    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

    # Start the new process
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    exit
    }

 # Run your code that needs to be elevated here
 Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue..."
 $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```